# Is it possible to override the "module" field in package.json?

Tags: npm, package.json, react-native-web

I am import React-Native-Web into my project and I was transpiling it when my transpiling process ran into errors that I wasn't familiar with.

After reading through it I realized that the library was offering me a transpiled version of the code, even though that was not what I was expecting.

https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/tree/master/packages/react-native-web

This is the source for the package, and in the .json file.

- "module": "dist/index.js"
- "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",

is there a way to tell npm which of these options to choose from?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like `import ModuleName from '~/react-native-web/desired/path/to/file'`.

You cant change the package json, because the changes wont be there when you `npm install` on other machine

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you!

Comment: glad i can help

Comment: wait shouldnt this be `import ModuleName from '~react-native-web/desired/path/to/file'` ?

Comment: `import { ComponentName } from 'react-native-web/dist'` was what specifically work